# $wpdb->delete column values IN ARRAY()?

Tags: php, database, mysql, wpdb

I am wondering if this is possible?

```
$wpdb->delete(
    'table_name',
    array('id' => array(1, 2, 3)),
    array('%d')
);
```

So, in this situation, it should remove 3 rows at once, and call the database only 1 time.  I have a lot of deletions that could be possible with my script and would rather it just perform the deletion once, instead of having to loop through all of the ids and do a `$wpdb->delete` on each one individually.  Is this possible?  Seems like it should be...

Comment: Have you tried it? Or better yet, [looked it up?](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Parameters)

Comment: Yes, I have looked at the function and didn't seem possible.  But honestly, this should be possible to do, as it's not much of a difference and would make sense to have in this function.

Comment: I don't understand why the downvote here... maybe whoever did it can help me to understand why?  Why the ignorance of asking if I looked it up?  Ofcourse I did, and thought I would ask anyways.  Isn't that what this site is for?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, `wpdb::delete` does *not* handle anything other than `WHERE field = X`. You can just use the `query` method instead:

```
$ids = implode( ',', array_map( 'absint', $ids ) );
$wpdb->query( "DELETE FROM table_name WHERE ID IN($ids)" );
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of the alternatives.  I don't see the relevance of using `absint` since that would only be relevant for UNSIGNED columns, and might not be the case.  But thanks for your alternate method example just the same.

Comment: Just demonstrating a level of sanitization; I doubt your ID's will be hard-coded?

Comment: Yes, ids are not hardcoded, they are within an array, so this is a good example, just not using `absint` I suppose.  Thanks anyways.

Comment: Ok then just use `intval` instead

Comment: True, I guess they should add this functionality in Wordpress though, seems simple enough to be added.  But until than, this answer is fine.

Comment: If you want this functionality, submit a [trac ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/) - that's the beauty of open source, it's built by all of us.